# Access Query Selecting only items with a max of a field below a certain number

Tags: ms-access

Ok so... I have this query :

```
SELECT * from Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderStatus os
ON o.Serial = os.Serial 
WHERE ( 
Select Max(StatusCode) FROM OrderStatus Where Serial = o.Serial  
) < 14;
```

I think this says select everything from both tables where the highest status code is less than 14

But it just selects everything (Every order has at least 1 status code associated with it below 14)

I also tried this :

```
SELECT * from Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderStatus os
ON o.Serial = os.Serial 
WHERE  Max(os.StatusCode) < 14;
```

But you can't use aggregate functions in access so it obv just errored.

Is there a way of filtering an access query so that it will only return rows where the highest status code of an order is below a specified number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Orders o
    INNER JOIN 
    OrderStatus os
        ON o.Serial = os.Serial 
WHERE o.Serial IN
    (
        SELECT Serial 
        FROM OrderStatus 
        GROUP BY Serial 
        HAVING MAX(StatusCode)<14
    )
```